# Trigger event for first entry in drop down list dy default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list created dynamically. The drop down list is seen only after user selects a radio button.
After selecting values in the drop down another table is dynamically filled up.
This currently works for any selection in drop down.

However the table is blank in the first instance when user selects the radio button. He needs to select 2nd entry first and then the table fills up. If then the user selects back the 1st entry then the table fills up correctly.

Hence is there any way to ensure that the event is triggered for the first entry in drop down by default without having the user to select anything first.

**JS File**

```
$('#domainSelect').on("change", function(){
        dropdownSelect = $("#domainSelect option:selected").text();
        var regionsArr = regions;
        if ($.isArray(regionsArr)){
            Object.keys(regionsArr).forEach(function (key) {
                  if(regionsArr[key]['region']== dropdownSelect){
                      var x=document.getElementById('DomainTable').rows;
                        x[0].cells[1].innerHTML=regionsArr[key]['name'];
                        x[1].cells[1].innerHTML=regionsArr[key]['deviceCount'];
                  }
                });
        }
    });
```

**JSP File:**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <select id="domainSelect">
                    <c:forEach items="${statsDomainList}" var="option">
                        <option value="${option.name}">${option.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trigger event once it is bound:

```
$('#domainSelect').on("change", function(){
  /**/
}).change(); // or .trigger('change');
```